# Put variable into SQL Statement (Java/SQL)

Tags: java, sql

So i have two tabels, Student and Klas_student which are described below.

**Student**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Studenten(
Studentenummer varchar(7) CHECK (Studentenummer ~'[0-9A-ZA-Z]{7}'),
}
```

**Klas**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Klas(
Student varchar(7) REFERENCES studenten (Studentenummer) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
Klas text NOT NULL REFERENCES Klas (Naam_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL
);
```

As you can see in Klas_student Student references to Studentnumber in Table Studenten. Now in java i need to take studentenummer from Studenten en put that in Klas_student.

To do that i execute a query and take all studentenummer from Studenten.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Studenten " + "VALUES ('1559335')";
statement2.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Then i want to take value from it and i do :

```
String studentnummer = result.getString(1).toString();
sqlStudenToKlas = "INSERT INTO Klas " + "VALUES (studentnummer)";
statement2.executeUpdate(sqlStudenToKlas);
conn.commit();
```

However in sqlStudentToKlas, it doesnt take the studentnummer(result.getString(1))string as an argument.

Anybody how i could pass the result.getString(1) as an argument/variable in Values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#:

You are Using **'@'** to passing parameter to your query string in ADO.net

```
String studentnummer = result.getString(1).toString();
sqlStudenToKlas = "INSERT INTO Klas " + "VALUES (@studentenummer)";
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@List", studentenummer);
statement2.executeUpdate(sqlStudenToKlas);
conn.commit();
```

And Use This Tutorial :[The C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06)

Java with JDBC:

```
String studentnummer = result.getString(1).toString();
sqlStudenToKlas = "INSERT INTO Klas " + "VALUES (?)";
sqlStudenToKlas.setString(1, studentenummer);
statement2.executeUpdate(sqlStudenToKlas);
conn.commit();
```

And Use This Tutorial :[Named Parameters for PreparedStatement](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here mistake:

```
sqlStudenToKlas = "INSERT INTO Klas " + "VALUES (studentenummer)";
```

you pass string studentenummer, instead of it's value. Try:

```
sqlStudenToKlas = "INSERT INTO Klas " + "VALUES (" + studentenummer+")";
```

or

```
sqlStudenToKlas = "INSERT INTO Klas " + "VALUES ('" + studentenummer+"')";
```

Comment: I want to pass value of the result ( string stundentnummer). if i apply your code my variable studentnummer is still never used anyway. At least thats what my IDE says. What i want is pass value of string studentnummer to field Student of Klas.

Comment: put System.out.println(studentnummer) after this

Comment: Thanks for you answer Pavlo. I took Hasan's answer as correct cause i think thats the way for the future and also good for other programmers.